# | Can't Access Web Setup Wizard | Welcome to Magento Admin

Tags: magento2

```
I am facing the above issue in my **live** store. Please let me know.

There is not a display proper page. I need to install some Extension via admin panel but I am not seeing that page proper as attached image.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Base URLs (Secure)
-> Use Secure URLs on Storefront -> Yes
-> Use Secure URLs in Admin -> Yes
-> Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) -> Yes
-> Upgrade Insecure Requests -> Yes
php bin/magento cache:clean + php bin/magento cache:flush.
```